Add constructor to class with extensions possible?
Is it possible to add an additional constructor to a class from a library with scala 3 extensions?
I have a class ClassA with two constructors ClassA() and Class(text: String, num: Int).
I want to add another constructor ClassA(text: String) with extensions.
I tried:
extension (classA: ClassA) 
  def apply(text: String): ClassA = classA.setText(text)

But I get:
val classA: ClassA = ClassA()("text") # this works, but is not what I want
val classA1: ClassA = ClassA("text")  # this does not work, but this is what I want

I also tried something like this:
extension (classA: ClassA) def this(text: String) = 
  this()
  classA.setText(text)

But I get a compilation error:

 is not accessible from constructor arguments

When I remove this() inside the method, the error message is as follows:

Auxiliary constructor must begin with call to 'this'

Any ideas?
Update:
Ok, I figured out that the desired behavior is possible with a companion object like this:
object ClassA: 
  def apply(text: String) = new ClassA().setText(text)

The downside of this is, that you do not import the original class from the library anymore but the companion object instead. Depending on the code, this could be confusing.
So I think this question is still relevant.

You were pretty close to the full solution. You cannot create extension methods on a constructor.
But you can create an extension method on a companion object:
class ClassA(val text: String, val num: Int) {
  def this() = this("", 0)
}
object ClassA {}


extension (companion: ClassA.type)
  def apply(text: String): ClassA = new ClassA(text, 0)

This works under these conditions:

you pay attention to ClassA() vs new ClassA syntax - while in Scala  every new ClassName(args) makes it possible to also call ClassName(args) if there is object ClassName companion which defines apply with the same arguments - it will overshade the new (def this). You can notice this with an array where new Array(int) (int: Int) creates an array of size int, and Array(int) creates an array of integers with a single value int. That said it only concerns def apply defined directly in the companion as I'll explain in a moment
your class has the companion object - e.g. in Jsoniter Scala there were methods missing that I could conveniently define on JsonCodec (e.g. inline def deriving = ... to allow using case class MyType() derives JsonCodec) but since there was no companion object for a while, it was not possible
extension methods are called ONLY then there is no existing class that the compiler knows can be called - so if you add an extension which has the same method's name+arguments as the extended type - the method on the original type will be called instead (so your def apply extension on a companion will not let you override the existing def apply there)
of course you have to import both your type AND the extension

So in practice you have to:

use the constructor calling convention without new keyword
make sure that there always is the companion (enums/case classes are guaranteed to have them, normal classes aren't)
creating extension on ClassName.type (this .type is important!) while making sure there are no conflicts with existing constructors (I'm sure that the behavior on the conflict would be deterministic, but I'm also sure nobody would bother remembering whether you overshade something you didn't supposed to or get an ignored extension, they would simply consider that confusing)

then you should get the behavior looking like adding constructor as an extension method.
